# How do I concatenate data from related tables using SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a historical database that we want to decommission some tables on (`Equipment`, `Capacity`), I have three related tables and I need to concatenate data from the `Capacity` table into the `Car` table.

```
-----------------        -----------------        -----------------
|  Car          |        |  Equipment    |        | Capacity      |
-----------------        -----------------        -----------------
|  CarId        |        |  CarId        |        | CapacityId    |
|  Make         |        |  EquipmentId  |        | EquipmentId   |
|  Model        |        |               |        | TotalSWL      |
|  SWL1         |        |               |        |               |
|  SWL2         |        |               |        |               |
-----------------        -----------------        -----------------
```

To give you some context, the `Car` table can have one `Equipment` record and each `Equipment` record for a car, can have many `Capacity` records, typically only two.

I want to copy the value from `TotalSWL` in `Capacity` to the `SWL1` and `SWL2` in `Car` but I don't know how to achieve this via a query and wondered if anyone could help?

**Example**

This is the desired outcome.

*Source*

```
-------------------------------------------
| CapacityId  |  EquipmentId  |  TotalSWL |
-------------------------------------------
| 1           |  2            |  100      |
| 2           |  2            |  50       |
-------------------------------------------
```

*Destination*

```
-------------------------------------------------
|  CarId  |  Make  |  Model   |  SWL1  |  SWL2  |
-------------------------------------------------
|  123    |  Ford  |  Fiesta  |  100   |  50    |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get two values using:

```
select c.*, ec.swl1, ec.swl2
from car c join
     (select e.carid, max(c.TotalSWL) as swl1,
             nullif(min(TotalSWL), max(TotalSWL)) as swl2
      from equipement e join
           capacity c
           on e.equipmentid = c.equipmentid
      group by e.carid
     ) ec
     on ec.carid = c.carid;
```

EDIT:

I do see tha the question is asking for an update:

```
update c
    set swl1 = ec.swl1,
        swl2 = ec.swl2
select c.*, ec.swl1, ec.swl2
from car c join
     (select e.carid, max(c.TotalSWL) as swl1,
             nullif(min(TotalSWL), max(TotalSWL)) as swl2
      from equipement e join
           capacity c
           on e.equipmentid = c.equipmentid
      group by e.carid
     ) ec
     on ec.carid = c.carid;
```

Comment: That's fantastic, whilst this approach gives me two columns with the information, I need to copy those values to a table.  How would that be achieved with this setup?

Comment: Thank you very much for the update.  I've tried to implement this solution but there is an error given of: `The multi-part identifier "ec.swl1" could not be bound.` and `The multi-part identifier "ec.swl2" could not be bound.`.  I've tried changing the order so that the select statement is above, just to test, but that's not worked.

Comment: I must add that the error only occurs in the `SET` portion of the query, the rest is error free.

Comment: But I see `swl1` in the subquery that is labeled `ec`.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I don't understand, they are there and they should be accessible.